# Creating a closed loop with vtkTubeFilter

Tags: python, python-3.x, 3d, vtk

**What I want**: Specify a set of points, specify the connectivity using `vtkCellArray` so that it becomes a closed circle, create a `vtkPolyData` from it and apply the `vtkTubeFilter` to give it some volume.

**What I get:** A loop that doesn't connect the first and last element correctly, despite explicitly defining that. The other confusing thing is, that the tubes seem to get wider approaching the misconnected start/end.

[image: this]

**What I did:** I started out with [this example](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/GeometricObjects/Display/PolyLine) from the VTK wiki on how to create a polyline. Here's the code (Python 3.4, VTK 7.0):

```
import vtk


def rendering(mapper):
    """Takes mapper and handles the rendering."""
    actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)

    # Create a renderer, render window, and interactor
    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
    renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)
    # Add the actors to the scene
    renderer.AddActor(actor)
    # Render and interact
    renderWindow.Render()
    renderWindowInteractor.Start()
    return

pts = vtk.vtkPoints()
pts.SetNumberOfPoints(4)
pts.SetPoint(0, 0.5, 0, 0)
pts.SetPoint(1, 1, 0.5, 0)
pts.SetPoint(2, 0.5, 1, 0)
pts.SetPoint(3, 0, 0.5, 0)

lines = vtk.vtkCellArray()
lines.InsertNextCell(5)
lines.InsertCellPoint(0)
lines.InsertCellPoint(1)
lines.InsertCellPoint(2)
lines.InsertCellPoint(3)
lines.InsertCellPoint(0)

poly = vtk.vtkPolyData()
poly.SetPoints(pts)
poly.SetLines(lines)

tubes = vtk.vtkTubeFilter()
tubes.SetInputData(poly)
tubes.CappingOn()
tubes.SidesShareVerticesOff()
tubes.SetNumberOfSides(4)
tubes.SetRadius(0.1)
tubes.Update()

mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputData(tubes.GetOutput())
rendering(mapper)
```

I hope somebody has any suggestions on how to fix this behaviour. I am thinking of a parameter in either `polydata` or `tubes` that I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

The tube filter does not support generating periodic tubes. You should be able to approximate the effect by making the seam (where tubes meet) collinear. So instead of

```
pts = vtk.vtkPoints()
pts.SetNumberOfPoints(4)
pts.SetPoint(0, 0.5, 0, 0)
pts.SetPoint(1, 1, 0.5, 0)
pts.SetPoint(2, 0.5, 1, 0)
pts.SetPoint(3, 0, 0.5, 0)

lines = vtk.vtkCellArray()
lines.InsertNextCell(5)
lines.InsertCellPoint(0)
lines.InsertCellPoint(1)
lines.InsertCellPoint(2)
lines.InsertCellPoint(3)
lines.InsertCellPoint(0)
```

you could do this:

```
pts = vtk.vtkPoints()
pts.SetNumberOfPoints(5)
pts.SetPoint(0, 0.25, 0.25, 0)
pts.SetPoint(1, 0.5, 0, 0)
pts.SetPoint(2, 1, 0.5, 0)
pts.SetPoint(3, 0.5, 1, 0)
pts.SetPoint(4, 0, 0.5, 0)

lines = vtk.vtkCellArray()
lines.InsertNextCell(6, range(5) + [0,])
```

You would probably want to turn CappingOff() since the seam will appear in the middle of a segment.

The "bump" will also move to the seam and appears to be a bug in VTK. You should search VTK's bug tracker and file a report if there's not already an issue listed.

Comment: This is the best workaround proposed so far, but [the bump is a problem](https://i.imgur.com/qlOOZxQ.png). VTK is working on their bug tracking system at the time, so I can't submit it.

Comment: I think this answer is as good as it gets, you might as well get the bounty for it!

Answer (score 1):

Though this is years ago, late comers might want to look at this PR: https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/merge_requests/2047

It didn't made into master, but using the changes, you can do this to get a closed tube from a looped polyline:

```cpp
    // Reset input polydata to a single cell, looped polyline
    double lpt0[3] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    double lpt1[3] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    double lpt2[3] = { 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
    double lpt3[3] = { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> pts = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
    pts->InsertNextPoint(lpt0);
    pts->InsertNextPoint(lpt1);
    pts->InsertNextPoint(lpt2);
    pts->InsertNextPoint(lpt3);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyLine> line
      = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyLine>::New();
    line->GetPointIds()->InsertNextId(0);
    line->GetPointIds()->InsertNextId(1);
    line->GetPointIds()->InsertNextId(2);
    line->GetPointIds()->InsertNextId(3);
    line->GetPointIds()->InsertNextId(0);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> cells
      = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();
    cells->InsertNextCell(line);

    inputPolyData = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
    inputPolyData->SetPoints(pts);
    inputPolyData->SetLines(cells);

    tubeFilter->SetInputData(inputPolyData);
    tubeFilter->LoopedOn();
    tubeFilter->Update();
```